# shell script to find dynamic public ip address in ubuntu does not show any output

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ip-address, tee

I wrote the following script to find my dynamic public IP address and save how often it is changes

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ip=0
change=0
for ((count = 10000; count != 0, change == 10; count--)); do

    fetch="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"
    dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com >>/home/nik/Desktop/file.txt
    if [ $ip == 0 ]; then
        ip=fetch
    elif [ $ip != "$fetch" ]; then
        change++
        echo $ip 
        echo " changed to "
        echo "$fetch"
        echo " at "
        echo date
    else
        echo ""
    fi
    echo "123"
    sleep 13
    (( count--))
done
```

I saved file as script.sh and changed it's executable permissions using

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

When I independently run dig command(in next line) or echo command directly in terminal, they log output to file without any problem

```
 dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com>>/home/nik/Desktop/file.txt
```

but when I run the script, It shows no output nor does it log anything into text file.
I use Ubuntu 19.10 if it matters.
Edit: added shebang and changed wait to sleep

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the bugs first.

Comment: Hey Naman! Could you add an example output? What should the file this script generates look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `change=0` in the beginning of your file, and then depend on `change == 10` in the conditional expression of your for loop.

I think you should review your code first :-)

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start with a script that tracks public IP Address changes might be this guy:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CURRENT_IP="$(timeout 5 dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com 2>/dev/null)"
num_changes=0
while [ 1 ]
do
    NEW_IP="$(timeout 5 dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com 2>/dev/null)"
    if echo "${CURRENT_IP}" | grep -q "${NEW_IP}"
    then
        echo "IP is the same" > /dev/null
    else
        let num_changes++
        echo "${num_changes}:  ${CURRENT_IP}   ->   ${NEW_IP}"
        CURRENT_IP="${NEW_IP}"
    fi
done
```

- There are two variables being used, `CURRENT_IP` and `NEW_IP`
- They are both being updated the same way `timeout 5 dig +short ... 2>/dev/null`
- The timeout serves to ensure our script never hangs forever
- The `2>/dev/null` serves to filter error messages away
- The `num_changes` variable keeps track of the number of times the IP changed
- The only time this script will ever print any message at all is when your address changes

Example output: [NUM_CHANGES]: [LAST ADDRESS]   ->   [NEW ADDRESS]

> 1: 75.72.13.89 -> 74.76.77.88
>   2: 75.72.13.88 -> 74.76.77.87
>   3: 75.72.13.87 -> 74.76.77.86